# PTIJ: When to say chatzi Kaddish

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Am I limited to saying half kaddish in the case where we only have 5 men, or if I only lost one parent?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Or ten people who are half-Jewish?

Answer (score 5):

Chetzi Kaddish does not mean a half-kaddish, rather it is an arrow-like kaddish.

So if you are like Yaakov Avinu, who prayed with sword and bow (see Bereishit 48:22 with Onkelos) then you can also say Chetzi Kaddish. Otherwise, I would avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

Chatzi Kaddish depends on the prayer being recited. For example, Chatzi Hallel must be followed by Chatzi Kaddish. It must also be recited following a short Chazarat Hashatz, Tachanun on days other than Monday and Thursday, and when you skip parts of Pesukei Dezimra, as well as if the Shaliach Tzibbur is going twice as fast as everyone else.

Otherwise, Kaddish Shalem must be recited.

Comment: do these require that you sing half a song, a chatzi shir?